# Convert List into Grid

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, pivot-table, list

I want to convert a List similar to the following into a grid (as below) so that I can generate pivot tables...  Is there an easy way to do this with VBA?

List:

```
Date        Name    Assignments
6/1/2020    Adams   Assignment 1
6/1/2020    Butler  Assignment 2
6/1/2020    Crump   Assignment 3
6/1/2020    Crump   Night
6/1/2020    Crump   Special
6/1/2020    Davis   Assignment 2
6/1/2020    Davis   Assignment 3
6/1/2020    Edwards Assignment 1
6/2/2020    Adams   Assignment 2
6/2/2020    Butler  Assignment 2
6/2/2020    Butler  Special
```

Table:

```
Date        Name    Assignment 1    Assignment 2    Assignment 3    Night   Special
6/1/2020    Adams   1               
6/1/2020    Butler                   1          
6/1/2020    Crump                                      1             1       1
6/1/2020    Davis                    1                 1        
6/1/2020    Edwards 1               
6/2/2020    Adams                    1          
6/2/2020    Butler                   1                                       1
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. It seems strange that you would want to convert to a grid in order to produce pivot tables. The data in its current format (list) is usually better for pivot tables. What kinds of counts or statistics do you want to get from these pivot tables? Please edit your post with something like "I want to count the number of assignments that each person completed by date/month" etc. If there are other columns in your data, please show a screenshot.

Comment: Agreed. In order to get from your "List" to "Table" above, I'd probably use... a Pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Power Query to convert the list?

1. Go to Data- From Range/Table:
   [image]
2. Select Assignments column- go to Transform- select Unpivot Columns:
   [image]
3. Select Value column- go to Transform- select Pivot Column- Value Column select Attribute:
   [image]

You can get the table you need.